# Rails 4: building a super simple api method and securing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guys what will be the best way to add one method in controller that will be exposed as an api to be used by another application (only one) to update some columns in database? I don't want to build a fancy api with versioning and all, it will be simple one method in controller exposed as api responding with json data. Also, how should I go about securing it?

Tech stack: `rails 4`, `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic and simple way to secure an API method is [HTTP Basic Auth](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html).

Just add one line on top of your controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "password"

  def update_columns
    ...
  end
end
```

Then don't forget to add these name and password to API call params in your other application.

PS. If you're using Rails in light API mode, you'll also need to include this module in your controller:

```
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add scope in your routes and add that controller method in request like

```
   scope '/api' do
     resources :chattings,only: [:create,:index,:show,:destroy] do 
       collection do
         get 'recent'
       end
     end
   end
```

and for security save api_secret in database which generate time of signin and secure every api with that api_secret in headers